# Decoding eval gzinflate base64_decode (Anyone Know of a Decoder I could Use for This)

Tags: eval, base64, spam, encryption

I want to make sure that this code is not harmful but everytime I try to decode it it doesn't actually do anything but give me even crazier looking symbols.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Below is the actual encrypted code...

```
eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode('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')))); ?>
```

Comment: as in the code is full of spam?  THATS WHAT IM TRYING TO FIGURE OUT!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out that it wasn't spam just a couple of links at the bottom of a wordpress footer...

jackass...

Answer (score 0):

I use this command to remove the nasty code from all PHP files from my /public_html folder:

```
find -name "*.php" -exec sed -i '/<?.*eval(gzinflate(base64.*?>/ d' '{}' \; -print
```

I hope it will help you.
Cheers!